# Migrating Access Tables to SQL Server - Beginner

Tags: migration, database-migration

I'm working in an Access 2007 database and need help migrating tables to SQL server. Is this possible to do having only purchased Access 2007 or do I need to download a separate program for SQL? When I try to create a new SQL database or open an existing one through Access, I'm getting a "CREATE DATABASE" or "CREATE TABLE" error and not sure what the issue is. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to install it. There is a free edition of SQL Server, called [Sql server express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/). Database size limit is 4gb. If it suits you go for it. Also, i belive Access has migration tool built in.

Update: In Access 2007 - Database Tools -> Move Data -> Sql Server ( follow the wizard ).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are you saying I can access SQL Server using the Access 2007 migration wizard as an alternative to downloading SQL Server Express? Or do I need to download SQL Server Express either way?

Comment: If you want to use SQL Server, of course you need to install it. It is not like Access (standalone database system). It runs service in background. Procedure I described is for moving data between Access and SQL Server. Before that you need to create database structure, or migrate ( like Gaby described ).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the microsoft's [SQL Server Migration Assistant 2005 for Access (v4.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=4ECD1E67-C64E-49E6-821E-C4D83D9D5FED&displaylang=en) which supports access 97 - 2007