# Copying Access 97 tables to SQL Server 2008 R2 64-bit daily

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2, openrowset

I have an ancient system that uses an Access 97 database to store information.  I want to copy the data from the 90-some tables to a SQL Server 2008 database on a daily basis.  I already have the tables defined in SS2008.

There is an equally ancient DTS job that has a separate box-line-box for each table.  I'd rather use an easier to maintain method that was written in code, not lines and boxes.  (yes, I know that SSIS lines and boxes are translated into XML, but that's kind of hard for me read and write.)

I can't use Linked Server or OPENROWSET because my SS2008 server runs as a 64-bit process, so the OLEDB Jet driver is not available.  The OLEDB MSOffice ACE 12.0 driver is 64-bit, but it isn't supposed to be used with database servers because it is not threadsafe (according to Microsoft).  Also, I can't get it to work ("Could not find installable ISAM") within SS2008 despite extensive research.  I can read the Access table with OLEDB Jet in a 32-bit program such as SSIS.

So, I'm looking for a modern, non-box-and-line, elegant 32-bit solution to copy the tables from the Access mdb/mdw file to SS2008.

Can I do this with:

- a single T-SQL script
- some C# thing that does introspection to determine table structure and then executes SQL for each table
- some magic "copy every table from this OLEDB to that SQL Server" package

There are several close dups of this question ([Copy access database to SQL server periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272865/copy-access-database-to-sql-server-periodically), [Migrating Access Tables to SQL Server - Beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125571/migrating-access-tables-to-sql-server-beginner)), but none that deal with the 32-bit limitation that makes OPENROWSET/Linked Server a non-option.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709670/how-do-i-import-ms-access-data-into-sql-server-using-ssis-package

Comment: thanks for the pointer, I had not seen that in my research.  unfortunately, to use that solution in this instance I'd have to generate 90 such box-line-box routes.  I'd rather a solution where I can loop through the tables and pull from Access and push to SQL (since the schemas are identical)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cast my vote for some C# thing. You may need to watch out for memory usage if you have large tables.

The basic idea goes like this:

```
foreach(tableName in access)
    get the table from access
    optionally clear the target table
    sqlbulkcopy it to target database
```

A more complicated solution would be to grab both tables and only update the changed rows.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  I introspected with GetOleDbSchemaTable, created tables with ExecuteNonQuery, then SqlBulkCopy to copy the data over.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably do it from within Access itself using VBA like the following:

```vbscript
Public Function CopyTableDataToSqlServer()
Dim tbd As DAO.TableDef, qdf As DAO.QueryDef, connStr As String
connStr = _
        "ODBC;" & _
        "Driver={SQL Server};" & _
        "Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
        "Database=cloneDB;" & _
        "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
For Each tbd In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If Not ((tbd.Name Like "MSys*") Or (tbd.Name Like "~*")) Then
        Debug.Print tbd.Name
        Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
        qdf.Connect = connStr
        qdf.SQL = "DELETE FROM [" & tbd.Name & "]"
        qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
        qdf.Execute
        Set qdf = Nothing
        CurrentDb.Execute _
                "INSERT INTO [" & connStr & "].[" & tbd.Name & "] " & _
                "SELECT * " & _
                "FROM [" & tbd.Name & "] ", _
                dbFailOnError
    End If
Next
Set tbd = Nothing
Debug.Print "Done."
End Function
```